# How to detect if backspace is hold

Tags: javascript, angular

How i can detect if backspace is pressed and Hold in js. I set event listener but it fires everytime when backspace is pressed i need to make difference between pressed and hold?

HTML Input:

```
(keydown)="fixIePosition($event);
```

TS Callback:

```
fixIePosition(e) {

    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') !== -1 ||
        navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') !== -1)
        && e.keyCode === 8) {
        const selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart;

        if (selectionStart === 3) {
            e.target.setSelectionRange(3, 3);
        // } else if (selectionStart === 5 && e.type === 'keydown') {
        //     console.log(e);
        //    // e.target.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionStart);
        //     this.ieFixPosition = true;
        } else if (selectionStart === 4 && e.type === 'keyup') {
            if (this.ieFixPosition) {
                e.target.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionStart);
                this.ieFixPosition = false;
            } else {
                e.target.setSelectionRange(selectionStart - 1, selectionStart - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code you've tried and we'll help

Comment: I have event listener on keydown but i have to make diffrence between pressed and hold

Comment: ok great, but if you don't show us how you're doing we won't be able to help

Comment: How do you define "hold"? 0.2 seconds? 1 second? 5 seconds? You'll need to set a timer and then cancel it if the key was released before it triggered. Remember that the OS may have it's own definition based on accessibility settings. Some users may have trouble typing due to impairments and thus will press and "hold" on a reglar basis.

Comment: keypress vs keydown/keyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out keyboard event [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) to detect key hold.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.repeat) {
            // Key Hold Event
        } else {
            // Key Press Event
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice. Too bad there's no IE support. Best part is that this will respect OS settings, so it's far more accessible than a custom timer.

Answer (score 1):

rxjs is the way to go for this;

```
(keydown.backspace)="backspaceDown($event) (keyup.backspace)="backspaceUp($event);
```

component:

```
// methods and subjects to handle sending key events
backspaceDown$ = new Subject();
backspaceDown(evt) {
  this.backspaceDown$.next(evt);
}

backspaceUp$ = new Subject();
backspaceUp(evt) {
  this.backspaceUp$.next(evt);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.backspaceDown$.pipe( // start a timer (however long you want) but cancel it if the up event fires
    switchMap(e => timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(e), takeUntil(this.backspaceUp$)))
  ).subscribe(event => this.fixIePosition(event));
}
```

you could generalize this behavior in a reusable directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[backspaceHold]'
})
export class BackspaceHoldDirective implements OnInit {

   @Output()
   backspaceHold = new EventEmitter();

   private keyDown$ = new Subject();
   @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event.target'])
   onKeyDown($event) {
     this.keyDown$.next($event);
   }

   private keyUp$ = new Subject();
   @HostListener('keyup.backspace', ['$event.target'])
   keyUp($event) {
     this.keyUp$.next($event);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.backspaceDown$.pipe( // start a timer (however long you want) but cancel it if the up event fires
       switchMap(e => timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(e), takeUntil(this.backspaceUp$)))
     ).subscribe(event => this.backspaceHold.next(event));
   }
}
```

for easy reuse like

```
(backspaceHold)="fixIePosition($event)"
```